# Is there any quick method to compute max of three values

Tags: c++, stl

In algorithm, I can use max to compute max for two values; is there any quick method to compute max for three values or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use c++11, you could use an initializer list:

```
int max = std::max({a,b,c,d});
```

working example http://ideone.com/36g1eq :

reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/

Answer (score 0):

```
int max1 = std::max(x, y);
int final_max = std::max(max1, z);
```

or `std::max_element`:

```
// min_element/max_element example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::min_element, std::max_element

bool myfn(int i, int j) { return i<j; }

struct myclass {
  bool operator() (int i,int j) { return i<j; }
} myobj;

int main () {
  int myints[] = {3,7,2,5,6,4,9};

  // using default comparison:
  std::cout << "The smallest element is " << *std::min_element(myints,myints+7) << '\n';
  std::cout << "The largest element is "  << *std::max_element(myints,myints+7) << '\n';

  // using function myfn as comp:
  std::cout << "The smallest element is " << *std::min_element(myints,myints+7,myfn) << '\n';
  std::cout << "The largest element is "  << *std::max_element(myints,myints+7,myfn) << '\n';

  // using object myobj as comp:
  std::cout << "The smallest element is " << *std::min_element(myints,myints+7,myobj) << '\n';
  std::cout << "The largest element is "  << *std::max_element(myints,myints+7,myobj) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/

Answer (score 0):

Fast, `constexpr` (compile-time), and generic ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b5aa695b7a307b2)):

```
template <typename F>
struct fold
{
    template <typename A>
    constexpr typename std::decay <A>::type
    operator()(A&& a) const { return std::forward <A>(a); }

    template <typename A, typename... An>
    constexpr typename std::common_type <A, An...>::type
    operator()(A&& a, An&&... an) const
        { return F()(std::forward <A>(a), operator()(std::forward <An>(an)...)); }
};

struct max_fun
{
    template <typename A, typename B>
    constexpr typename std::common_type <A, B>::type
    operator()(A&& a, B&& b) const
        { return a > b ? std::forward <A>(a) : std::forward <B>(b); }
};

using max = fold <max_fun>;

int main ()
{
    cout << ::max()(5, 9, -2, 0.1) << endl;
}
```

This is faster than any solution involving a run-time iteration on a container, because there is no pointer incrementing and no dereferencing. It is equivalent to a hard-coded sequence of ternary `?:` operators.

It accepts any number of arguments of arbitrary types, as long as `std::common_type` is defined for them.

As a `constexpr` function, it can be used to compute an integral value at compile time and use it e.g. as a template argument.

You can easily have any fold/reduce/accumulate operation other than `max` by just replacing `max_fun` with another function object.